# Duplicates in "Company Name" dropdown under "Current position" on Stack Overflow profile page

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, developer-story

In the "Edit profile" page on Stack Overflow, I see that there are multiple "Experis IT" and "EXPERIS - MANPOWER GROUP" options in the drop-down list for "Company Name" (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of the company name dropdown on stackoverflow]

How does this happen? Is this a bug?

Yesterday I set the company name for my profile to be "Experis Ciber AS" manually (without selecting an option in the drop-down).

I asked my coworkers today if they can see the "Experis Ciber AS" option in the dropdown when they edit their profile, but there are none.

Does it take a while before "Experis Ciber AS" is available as an option for other users?

If my coworker also puts in "Experis Ciber AS" manually, will there be two "Experis Ciber AS" later on, or just one?

I suspect that the duplicates in this drop-down is from multiple users who added the same company name roughly at the same time before Stack Overflow added said company name to the dropdown list.

If this is an old bug that has been fixed, and new duplicates are merged automatically once the system catches up to all the new company names added, why haven't the duplicates of "Experis IT" and "EXPERIS - MANPOWER GROUP" been merged?

If this is a new bug then I suggest that all company names that are identical will be merged automatically (feature-request).

Thanks for reading this wall of text! :)